# How to cast Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application.Run result in vb.net?

Tags: vb.net, vba

I have the following code:

```
Dim technologyMapping = oXL.Run("GetTechnologyMapping")
```

The result is an object. In my VBA (macro) code, I return a `Collection` as shown below:

```
Public Function GetTechnologyMapping() As Collection
    ' ...
    Set GetTechnologyMapping = result
End Function
```

I am trying to cast via `CType` and `CTypeDynamic` but had now luck so far. Every time the code throws an Exception, that I cannot cast this object although the object has the property `Count`. How do I cast this object to a collection?

Comment: You run a macro, the only person that knows what it returns is you.  Collection is drastically unlikely, the vb.net type is not a VBA type.  Look at the macro code.

Comment: The second listing shows the important part of the macro. Yes, it is a collection.

Comment: A Collection returned by VBA code is not directly usable in VB.NET, it is a private VBA type so casting is not possible.  You have to keep it Object and use late-bound code.

Comment: Ok, Thanks. I thought `VBA.Collection == VB.Collection`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can cast a `VBA.Collection` to a `System.Collections.IEnumerable`.  This will allow you to enumerate the collection with a `For Each` loop.

Something like this:

```
Sub Test(wbPath As String)
    Dim app As New Excel.Application
    Dim wb As Excel.Workbook = app.Workbooks.Open(wbPath)
    Dim result As Object = app.Run("ReturnCollection")
    wb.Close(Excel.XlSaveAction.xlDoNotSaveChanges)
    app.Quit()

    Dim colAsIEnumerable As System.Collections.IEnumerable = TryCast(result, System.Collections.IEnumerable)

    If colAsIEnumerable IsNot Nothing Then
        For Each o As Object In colAsIEnumerable
            If o IsNot Nothing Then Debug.Print(o.ToString())
        Next
    End If
End Sub
```